# Understanding why proving a hint will prove that $D_{6} \cong S_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions, dihedral-groups

Recall that the dihedral group $D_{6} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{6} \rtimes _{\phi} \mathbb{Z}_{2},$ where the reflection $\mu$ acts on the rotation $\rho$ by \begin{equation*}
    \prescript{\mu}{}{\rho} = \rho^{-1}.
\end{equation*} Show that we also have: $$D_{6} \cong S_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}.$$ Hint: Label the vertices of a regular hexagon $1,2,3,4,5,6$ consecutively, and consider the stabilizer of the set $\{ 2,4,6 \}$ by the action of $D_{6}$ on the set of vertices.

**My question is:**

I do not know how considering the stabilizer of the set $\{ 2,4,6 \}$ by the action of $D_{6}$ on the set of vertices of the regular hexagon will prove that $D_{6} \cong S_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}.$ Could anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: The stabilizer of this set is exactly the symmetries of the triangle formed by those vertices (and note that $S_3\cong D_3$).

Comment: And why we need the symmetries of the triangle formed by those vertices and what is the importance of $S_{3}$ being isomorphic to $D_{3}$? could you clarify more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $D_6$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $S_3$, namely the stabilizer of $\{2,4,6\}$.

It also has a two element subgroup, isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$, whose intersection with $S_3$ is trivial (consider a reflection that doesn't stabilise $\{2,4,6\}$.)

By counting $S_3\Bbb Z_2=D_6$.

Thus $D_6\cong S_3×\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: And what is the importance of stating that it is the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ ?

Comment: Dihedral groups cannot be written as the direct product of cyclic groups. The following has the intuition for semidirect products: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704410/intuition-about-the-semidirect-product-of-groups/3590049#3590049

Comment: @Smart20 so we know what group we are talking about

Comment: How can I count $S_{3}\mathbb{Z}_{2}$? can you give me an example of counting one element of it please?

Comment: $S_3$ is a normal subgroup, because it is of index two.  If follows that $S_3\Bbb Z_2$ is a subgroup.  But, because of the presence of the identity in each of $S_3$ and $\Bbb Z_2$, $S_3$ and $\Bbb Z_2$ are proper subgroups of $S_3\Bbb Z_2$.  But by Lagrange the order has to divide the order of the group.  It follows that $S_3\Bbb Z_2$ is too big to be anything but the whole group.

Comment: In this statement "It also has a two element subgroup, isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$, whose intersection with $S_3$ is trivial (consider a reflection that doesn't stabilise $\{2,4,6\}$.)
" ..... Why should I consider a reflection and not rotation?

Comment: But how should we calculate the left cosets of $S_{3}$ in $D_{6}$? or in our case we should calculate the left cosets of the stabilizer of $\{2,4,6\}$?

Comment: There's one rotation you could use.  A reflection is just the first thing I thought of, since they all have order two.  No real need for cosets.  We are just checking that the definition of a direct product are met.

Comment: This is a question about your answer here (if you want to answer it I would appreciate that)

Comment: Sure.  All I have used is that $S_3$ and $\Bbb Z_2$ are subgroups with $S_3\cap\Bbb Z_2=\emptyset$ and $S_3\Bbb Z_2=D_6$.  This means by definition that $D_6\cong S_3\times\Bbb Z_2$.  Is it a different part you are stuck on?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3854252/showing-that-d-6-has-a-two-element-subgroup-isomorphic-to-bbb-z-2-whose?noredirect=1#comment7951450_3854252  I am sorry I forgot to put the link :)

Comment: Yeah I am speaking about a different part. Also can not we take the center instead of this subgroup of order 2 that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}?$

Comment: Yes we can.  None of the $\Bbb Z_2$'s stabilize $\{2,4,6\}$.  The center is, as you know, generated by the rotation through $\pi$.

Comment: How did you know that the center is the rotation by $\pi$?

Comment: It's well-known:  for odd $n$, the center of $D_{2n}$ is trivial, and for even $n$, it is $\{\rho,e\}$, where $\rho$ is rotation through $\pi$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113806/discussion-between-chris-custer-and-math).